# How to create array of object references in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I want to create an array of object references for a class , but don't want to actually create objects to assign into array . How can I do so. ?

Comment: Um, `Foo[] array = new Foo[10];`? It's not clear what you've tried or what's going wrong...

Comment: can you elaborate your question?

Comment: Explain why you want to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are used to store primitive values and objects. For example, we can create an array of String or any class objects. 
To explain, Lets create a class Employee containing a single instance variable empId. Following is the definition of this class.

```
class Employee{
   int empId;
}
```

An array of objects is created just like an array of primitive type data items in the following way.

```
Employee[] EmployeeArray = new Employee[10];
```

The above statement creates the array which can hold references to ten Employee objects. It doesn't create the Employee objects themselves. 
They have to be created separately using the constructor of the Employee class. The EmployeeArray contains ten memory spaces in which the 
address of ten Employee objects may be stored. If we try to access the Employee objects even before creating them, run time errors would occur.

The Employee objects have to be instantiated using the constructor of the Employee class and their references should be assigned to the array elements in the following way.

```
EmployeeArray[0] = new Employee();
```

In this way, we create the other Employee objects also. If each of the Employee objects have to be created using a different constructor, we use a statement similar to the above several times. However, in this particular case, we may use a for loop since all Employee objects are created with the same default constructor.

```
for ( int i=0; i<EmployeeArray.length; i++) {
EmployeeArray[i]=new Employee();
}
```

The above for loop creates ten Employee objects and assigns their reference to the array elements.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to create an array of object references for a class

```
ClassName [] classesArray = new ClassName [size];
```

That creates an array.

> but don't want to actually create objects to assign into array.

You haven't created any objects till now. Just don't assign.

Comment: how can a parametrized constructor can be called using one of these references keeping object creation out of the scenario ? is it even possible ?

Comment: You can simply pass this `cassesArray` which is empty. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can write `new Foo[n]` where `n` evaluates to a non-negative integer. This will create an array of size `n` that will be initialised to `null` `Foo` references.

In practice, you'll *assign* that to something else it could be immediately garbage-collected or perhaps optimised out altogether:

`Foo[] a = new Foo[n];`

Answer (score 0):

This is normal array.

```
int [] xr = new int[5];
```

after creating an array you can assign values to this elements.

```
xr[0]=100;
```

next we will see what is object reference array.

```
employee [] person = new employee[4];
```

There are 5 elements in this object array.Type of this array is employee.like int long short..etc. and this array has 5 elements.All the elements are persons.Now we can assign a value to this object array. See carefully!

```
person[0]= new employee();
```