# Implement composition and aggregation in Java

Tags: java, arrays, collections

I have 4 Classes

```
public class Book {
private String title;
    private Autor[] autors;
    private Collection<Chapter> chapters;

    public Book(String title, Autor[] autors, Chapter[] chapters){
        this.title = title;
        this.autors = autors;
        this.chapters = new ArrayList<Chapter> ();
    }
}
```

Between Book and Autor I have Agreggation, thats why I use an array in Book for Autor

```
public class Autor {

    private String name;
    private Date dateBirth;
    private String afiliation;

    public Autor(String name, Date dateBirth, String afiliation){
        this.name = name;
        this.dateBirth = dateBirth;
        this.afiliation = afiliation;
    }
}
```

Between Book and Chapters I have composition and that's why I have a collection of chapters in Book

```
public class Chapter {

    private String title;
    private List <Section> sect;

    public Chapter(String title, List sect){
        this.title = title;
        this.sect = sect;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

And also between Chapter and Section I have composition and that's why I have a List of sections

```
public class Section{

    private String title;

    public Section(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }   
}
```

My problem is now when I want to instantiate Book I don't know how to give the arguments as collection, array of autors

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Autor[] autors = new Autor[]{
            autors[0] = new Autor("Simin Lebanon", new Date(23, 07, 1974), "Lincoln University"),
            autors[1] = new Autor("John Wayne Evald", new Date(15, 01, 1966), "Preston University"),
            autors[2] = new Autor("Ildiko Philipa", new Date(07, 11, 1989), "Minesota University")
        };

        Chapter[] chapters = new Chapter[2];
        chapters[0] = new Chapter("Introduction", section);

        Book eOROOS = new Book("Design Patterns Vol 1", autors[0], chapters[0]);
    }
}
```

Eclipse tell me to change the constructor Book(String, Autor[], Chapters[]) to Book(String, Autor, Chapter), but I don't want that because I will lose the agreggation and composition

Comment: Hint: be consistent - why using arrays here; and lists there?!

Comment: if you access an array with an index (e..g., `authors[0]`), the type of this expression is the type of the array (in your case, an `Author`). What your constructor expects is an `Author[]` (`Author`-array). If you write `authors` instead of `authors[0]`, it should work. Sidenote: why do you use an `Author[]`, but a `List<Section>`? I would recommend using a `List` in all your cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create array of object references in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876858/how-to-create-array-of-object-references-in-java)

Comment: Thanks now it works. But I put there chapters and he see's nothing. I had to create a method inside Book class.
I used Array and List because I don't know generics very good, and this program is for learning porpouse.